# Finding rivers from GeoTIFF files with GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, rivers

I've grabbed a bunch of `.tif`-files (from http://dwtkns.com/srtm/) and I am trying to render it in 3D as terrain.

I've converted it to a 16-bit heightmap successfully but I am curious is there any way I can get a rivers-map/texture from GDAL? If there is no tool for this is there any algorithm to detect rivers?

Comment: Why bother if you are using srtm, they have already been extracted in [hydrosheds](https://www.hydrosheds.org).

Comment: @Hornbydd I have downloaded the data sets - but what tools can I use to convert that river data into images/textures?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by image or texture, the data from hydrosheds is already in a raster format?

Comment: The final product I need is essentially a PNG/JPEG image - what tools can I use to convert the Hydroshed data into that? The same way I can use GDAL to convert those GeoTiff data into a PNG heightmap

Comment: If you are going to create images from the data I would use a GIS system something like QGIS if you want to do it for free then you can play with the symbology, get it just right then export as a jpeg. Doing it from GDAL and scripting without seeing what you are really symbolising sounds like a recipe for disaster to me?

Comment: Great suggestion! QGIS seems like the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hornbydd suggested for rivers it is way better to download existing dataset. E.g. from [hydrosheds](https://www.hydrosheds.org/page/hydrorivers) or [OSM](http://download.geofabrik.de/) (waterways and water layers). And clip that dataset to your study area.

You can relatively easily extract drainage. E.g. with Grass tools as suggested in other answer. If that is all you need, good.

But drainage is far from rivers, depending on detail/resolution you require, rivers are more likely areas (polygons). Getting a nice river network with perennial streams only, and excluding other drainage network, is mission impossible with SRTM data only.

Also for rendering purpose, you can use some satellite imagery. E.g. list of some sources on [EOS website](https://eos.com/blog/7-top-free-satellite-imagery-sources-in-2019/). You do not describe your 3D rendering technique. In open source GIS world you can use QGIS software to create 3D rendering with SRTM raster, and drape almost any GIS data (including OSM data mentioned above) in various formats as layers on it including opacity and even 3D objects.

QGIS has even an option to use OSM data as service - in multiple styles e.g. via Quick Map Services plugin. Everything already styled, all you need is load it as layer, load your SRTM and make 3D view of it.

Comment: Hydrosheds provides datasets for say rivers - but are there any tools or programs to convert that into plain images?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Added another idea for 3D rendering to my answer, and basic info what to do.

Comment: I am making the renderering engine myself. What I need is a texture/image of river data only. Is that possible to get from those sources?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Yes it is. But there are so many options and without knowing what exactly you want to do it is hard to recommend one. E.g. you can style waterways and water layers from OSM in QGIS and save map as image (PNG with transparency / TIF etc.) with exact SRTM raster extent and resolution if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are various implementations of watersheds and hydrology delineation using the the A* algorithm. For instance in [grass gis r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.watershed.html) and [python pysheds](https://mattbartos.com/pysheds/).

In this instance I recommend the grass gis implementation as the method was developed on SRTM data.